# String parse to int in go language

Tags: string, go

I have a string like "en=10 , ab=15". I want to get 10 as an int from this. I cant cast the types it always returns ASCII codes. Should I convert it to map?

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
i := strings.Index(st, "=")
```

then

```
n, err := fmt.Sscan(st[i+1:], &d)
```

try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/XVqNtKXLcG):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    st := "en=10 , ab=15"
    i := strings.Index(st, "=")
    if i != -1 {
        var d int
        n, err := fmt.Sscan(st[i+1:], &d)
        if err != nil || n != 1 {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(d)
    }
}
```

output:

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
package main
import "strconv"
import "fmt"

func main() {
i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(#YOURSTRING#, 0, 64)
fmt.Println(i)
}
```

It should then parse it into an int

Answer (score 0):

You should split the string and then convert it the individual components to int.

```
var splits = strings.Replace("en=10 , ab=15", ",", "=")
splits =  strings.split(splits, "=")
for var i := 0; i < splits.Len(); i++ {
  splits[i].toInt()
}
```